# my string become null then i am getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:1

Tags: java

In my code

```
for(int i=1; i<submenuCap.toString().length();i++){
     String[] parts = captionRes.getString(i).split("[*]");
     String part1 = parts[0]; 
     String part2 = parts[1];
    System.out.println("First parts: "+part1+" 2nd Part: "+part2);
 }
```

Here in my `submenuCap.toString.length()` is 30, and some values are like `""`, `"LOTO Equipment Issue & Return Record*0"` and `"Some Equipment Issue & Return Record*1"` etc..

I want to split only when data != `""`, then get last index values either 0 or 1 according to data, but here I am getting o/p

```
 First parts: LOTO Energy Isolation Record 2nd Part: 0
 First parts: LOTO Equipment Issue & Return Record 2nd Part: 0
 First parts: UPS Visitor Entry Record 2nd Part: 0
 First parts: Daily Technical Observation Record 2nd Part: 0
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at com.dao.DaoImpl.getMappingCategoryData(DaoImpl.java:240)
 at com.services.ServiceImpl.getMappingCategoryData(ServiceImpl.java:30)
 at com.controller.MasterController.getMappingCategoryData(MasterController.java:71)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Please use full words, for example, what does _getting o/p_ mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a check if split function returns an array having atleast two elements.

```
for(int i=1; i<submenuCap.toString().length();i++){
     String[] parts = captionRes.getString(i).split("[*]");
     if(parts.length >1){ // check added.
        String part1 = parts[0]; 
        String part2 = parts[1];
        System.out.println("First parts: "+part1+" 2nd Part: "+part2);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yes Dear it is the best solution Thanks...@ruhul

Answer (score 0):

Add and check the  conditions

```
  for(int i=0; i<submenuCap.toString().length();i++){
       if(captionRes.getString(i)!=null&&!captionRes.getString(i).isEmpty()){
          String[] parts = captionRes.getString(i).split("[*]");
          //It would be better checking array size before processing by index
          String part1 = parts[0]; 
          String part2 = parts[1];
          System.out.println("First parts: "+part1+" 2nd Part: "+part2);
      }else{
          //Other logic      
      }
   }
```

Comment: Ya you are also right @Lakshman Miani Thank you..For help me